# WPF rendering issues on 32bit Windows 7 and Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF application that i try to install on severals VM. On every 64bit Windows it works fine but on every 32 bit windows, the WPF application UI responds awkwardly.

Is there something special to do for WPF application on a 32bit machine ?

Comment: check for dotnet version

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"UI responds awkwardly"*?

Comment: I have a Windows mobile style application. When i click on a menu button, part of the interface changes, and the rest dont, but some other parts reveal themselves as you enter in with your mouse cursor

Comment: For 32 bit try software rendering: RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly; (see: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jgoldb/2010/04/12/whats-new-for-performance-in-wpf-in-net-4/)

Comment: @swiszcz : thanks a lot you solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @swiszcz lead, i managed to solve the rendering issue on Win 7 and Win 8.1 x86 VM by adding the code below on the application startup method :

```
RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = System.Windows.Interop.RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
```

Edit : to be totally optimum, i now check if the program is running on a physical machine or on a virtual machine. On a virtual machine i set the RenderMode to SoftwareOnly and on a physical machine i set the RenderMode to Default.

Here is the code to do so :

```
public partial class App : Application
{

    public App()
    {
        Startup += Application_Startup;
        Exit += Application_Exit;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Detect if the local machine is a virtual or a physical one
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True if the local machine is virtual, False if the local machine is physical</returns>
    private bool IsVirtualMachine()
    {
        using (var searcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem"))
        {
            using (var items = searcher.Get())
            {
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    string manufacturer = item["Manufacturer"].ToString().ToLower();
                    if ((manufacturer == "microsoft corporation" && item["Model"].ToString().ToUpperInvariant().Contains("VIRTUAL"))
                        || manufacturer.Contains("vmware")
                        || item["Model"].ToString() == "VirtualBox")
                    {
                        return true;
                    }

                    // Check "HypervisorPresent" property, which is available in some cases.
                    var hypervisorPresentProperty
                      = item.Properties
                            .OfType<PropertyData>()
                            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "HypervisorPresent");

                    if ((bool?)hypervisorPresentProperty?.Value == true)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

   private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        //Alter the rendering for the virtual machine (see Bug 
        if (this.IsVirtualMachine())
            RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = System.Windows.Interop.RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
        else
            RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = System.Windows.Interop.RenderMode.Default;

    }
}
```

Comment: You should note that even a physical machine with a problematic video card driver can let WPF apps suffer. Thus, you should provide your end users a way to configure software rendering, not merely hard code.

Comment: Maybe you're right, i will think about let it managable via .config file, not a end user parameter but definitly something an advanced support user would do. Thx for the making me aware of this issue

Answer (score 0):

I Assume that you're using the Click Once option of deployment, you will need to first check all of you dependencies and make sure all are compatible with x86 and if they then go into your projects properties make sure that under Build there Platform target make sure Any CPU is checked. This is where I would start.

Comment: Actually i am using WIX to install all the dependencies. I will check the build setup

Comment: All projects are already set to x86 in Build/Platform Target propertiy. It works fine on any x64 Windows. Is it possible to be linked with the VM ? I dont know if htis problem will occur on a real installation... and i have no way to ckeck it anyway